# how to import a Talend ETL project

Tags: java, etl, talend

I'm a freshman on Talend ETL(Jasper ETL), now I have a project with a process folder, a talend.project and a .project files. I want to import them but don't know how to do it.

I try to compress them as a zip file and import, but I get the error message says `FeatureNotFoundException: Feature bigDate' not found`

Answer (score 0):

in ETL (New version or updated),

1. Create a new Project in ETL
2. in Job Design, rigth click, Import Items
3. Find your files in the folder
4. Select items to import and next...

Finish

Regards!